# How to append a string to a magento success page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm making a customization of [this module](http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/) for my personal magento module for an external gateway.
I need to create a redirect URL for success page like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/success?payementID=12345678

Is it correct to use this way?

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true, '_query'=>'?paymentID=12345678'));
```

Can you tell me how to do?

Comment: `payementID != paymentID`

Comment: What you mean?... payementID = paymentID

Comment: It's a typo. Presume accidental but if not then there's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code below inside your redirect function

```
$redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/success',array('_query'=>array('paymentID' => '12345678'),'_secure' => true));

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply you mean i have to use my code: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true, '_query'=>'?paymentID=12345678'));  and after this your code $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/success',array('_query'=>array('paymentID' => '12345678'),'_secure' => true));

Comment: Use this inside the redirect function Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect($redirectUrl); I dont know why you need Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action:: instead of $this or Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);